# Python chatserver - Unable to close server because of blocking call

Tags: python, sockets, blocking

I'm writing a chat server in Python for an assignment. However, I am having an issue shutting down the server. Here's what's happening:

When a client connects, I spawn two threads: `readThread` and `writeThread`. `readThread` is responsible for reading data from the client and printing it to `stdout`, and `writeThread` is responsible for reading a message from `stdin` and sending it to the client.

When the client sends `'EXIT'`, I want to shutdown the server. My `writeThread` runs in a loop like this:

```
def write(self) :
        while self.dowrite :
            data = sys.stdin.readline().strip();            
            self.conn.send(data);
        print 'WriteThread loop ended';
```

Now, when I receive `EXIT`, I set `dowrite` to false, but, of course, that doesn't break the while loop because of the blocking call `sys.stdin.readline().strip()`.

So, what happens is: to disconnect, the client needs to send `EXIT`, and then I need to hit return on the console. Is there any way I can work around this, so that when the client sends the exit message, I immediately break out of the while loop in `write()`.

**EDIT**
How it comes together:

The main thread spawns two threads : `read` and `write`, and then waits (joins) for `read` to finish. `Read` finishes when it reads `EXIT`. As soon as the `read` thread ends, the main thread continues and sets `dowrite` to false in the write thread, which should end the write loop, but that can only happen once the while loop iterates one more time.

Comment: Not 100% sure I understand where your signals come together but could you just raise an exception when you get the exit signal? (and then catch it outside the loop).  That way it'll break through anything else.

Comment: can you send a signal up to the main thread that read is finished and then have the main thread kill the other thread? (or vice versa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make child threads to be daemons:

```
t.daemon = True
```

Daemon threads will stop if your program exits.

You could use [an event](http://docs.python.org/library/threading#event-objects) to notify other threads about it. In the thread where the event occured:

```
event.set() # event occurred
```

In other threads:

```
event.wait() # wait for event
```